# Can I extract the columns/fields and logic used in an XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I am specifically looking to parse the XSLT to retrieve the fields in the input XML and also get the logic between the input and output data been generated,

I am not sure, but have i been given a target to create an XSLT parser which is like a sub module in a browser?

It is more like reverse engineer some code to get the source and map it to the destination data.

Comment: What do you mean by extracting logic ? You can certainly extract columns/fields.

Comment: **By def:** XSLT transforms XML documents into other XML documents, or other formats such as HTML for web pages, plain text or XSL Formatting Objects, which may subsequently be converted to other formats, such as PDF, PostScript and PNG.

Comment: @Vebbie: Logic such as some logical loop, if clauses, etc for example - check if a field is blank then pick up another field

Comment: @Vebbie: Can we extract the columns been used in the XSLT without the original XML?

Comment: Could you provide some more information on what exactly you're trying to accomplish in your original question?

Comment: I think the answer is `Yes` for both of your questions.

Comment: You can provide minimal code of your input source, expected output and xslt tried to achieve the result, if you get stuck anywhere. So that the wonderful people of the community can help to solve the same. Thanks.

Comment: XSLT is Turing complete and your question resembles asking for termination. You need to restraint the types of transformation to analyze (ie. one to one relationship between elements in the input and elements in the output). Also, you might not make absolute inferences about hierarchy of input nor output. Do note that Schemas (XS, DTD, NG) are related but orthogonal to transformations.